Issue setting the MPN (Microsoft Partner Network) id to an App Registration
I have an MPN id and I'm trying to set this id on the "Branding & properties" section to have the verified badge on the logging process of my apps.
I've tried to use the Graph API, Graph CLI and set this programatically with C# but I'm having issues.
When I use a token generated by the App Registration that was used to create the App Registration I want to update, I receive a 404 error in Postman and when I use a token generated by the App Registration I’m trying to update, I receive a 403 error.
What will be the minimum permission required to update the App Registration to set the MPN id?
Mother APP Registration permissions

App registration to update permissions

Graph API request with postman

Graph CLI


Does the user has one of the role assigned Application Administrator or Cloud Application Administrator Refer this MsDoc.

The child App Registrations are created automatically when a Managed Application is deployed, using a parent App Registration (referred to as the "Mother" App Registration) as a template. I am trying to enable the verified publisher badge for each deployed application's log in, where each deployed managed app has its own associated App Registration. The company has already completed the Partner verification process.

Can you try and check by adding Microsoft Partner Center delegated type user_impersonation API permission to your registered application and generate access token. Refer this MsDoc and let me know it works or not?

Add Delegated type API permission of Application.ReadWrite.All and generate access token and use the same access token.


Error: Insufficient priveleges to complete the operation

As mentioned in this MsDoc,To resolve the error and to set the verifiedPublisherID you should have at least  Delegated type Application.ReadWrite.All API Permission.
Registered Microsoft Entra Single Tenant Application, Added and Granted Delegated type Application.ReadWrite.All  API permission like below:

To generate the access token for Delegated type Application.ReadWrite.All using authorization_code flow.
Firstly, To get code, I ran below authorization request in browser:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
&client_id=<app_id>
&redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default



Now, I generated Access token using authorization_code flow :
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token 
client_id=<app_id>
client_secret = <client_secret>
redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
code=<code which generated from browser>
scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type = authorization_code



Use same access token in to set verified publisher:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/setVerifiedPublisher

Content-type: application/json

{
    "verifiedPublisherId": "<ID>"
}


If operation successful, this method returns a 204 No Content response code.
Reference:
SetVerifiedPublisher
